# How to specify the schema of a reusable request body parameter in OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: openapi

The [swagger docs site](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/) shows an example for this case, but it does not follow through all the way to show the definition of the `Pet` schema.

E.g.:

```
paths:
  /pets:
    post:
      summary: Add a new pet
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/PetBody'
  /pets/{petId}
    put:
      summary: Update a pet
      parameters: [ ... ]
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/PetBody'
components:
  requestBodies:
    PetBody:
      description: A JSON object containing pet information
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
```

I don't understand where the request body parameter names go in this scenario. I want to see the definition of `#/components/schemas/Pet`.  For [query parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#common-for-various-paths) you have the `components/parameters` where you can define a `name` and a `schema` for each parameter. But I don't see the equivalent for the request body parameters. For example if I have a `POST /api/pets` with an `application/json` body of:

```
{ "name": "Fluffy", "type": "cat", "legs": 4 }
```

Where do I describe the parameters `name`, `type` and `legs` including their names?

Also on an unrelated topic it would be nice if there was a tag for OpenAPI v3.0 (not sure how to create one)

Also possible related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218457/how-to-define-a-reusable-body-parameter-that-is-a-primitive-data-type-in-openapi).

Answer (score 2):

After scouring the swagger docs I think I understand it now, I think the `Pet` schema would be:

```
components:
   schemas:
      Pet:
         type: object
         properties:
            name:
               type: string
            type:
               type: string
            legs:
               type: integer
         required:
            - type
```

I was missing out on the `properties` attribute.